# Good references for Fluid/Solid physical properties

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, solid-mechanics

I need good references for Fluid (Equation Of State, Heat capacity, thermal conductivity, radiation properties...) and Solid (Elasticity modulus, stress-strain data, heat capacity, thermoelasticity, thermal conductivity,...).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about them? Tables of their values? Models that predict them with moore or less accuracies? Definitions of them? Descriptions of experimental methodologies to measure them?

Comment: What type of materials? Explosives, pure metals, alloys... And what kind of fluids under what conditions? Gases, liquids, supercritical, subcritical, multiphase...

Comment: I'd like to use them in Fluid/Solid mechanics. So for fluid(Gas/Liquid/Vapor), i'll need the parameters value for ideal gas, cubic equation of state (Critical pressure, temperature,...) and Tait Equation. The tables will be fine for thermal conductivity, prandtl number, specific heat capacity (Cv/Cp), absorption/scattering/refractive index... For solid, High/Low pressure materials, strain-stress data (tables whatever the accuracy), specific heat, thermal conductivity, specific latent heat for Solid-Fluid transitions if possible